# How can I calculate the amplitude of a signal from its power in dBm?

Tags: signal-power

$$\begin{align}
P_\text{out} &= 51.787\text{dBm}\\
P_\text{out} &= 10\log_{10}\frac{A_\text{out}^2}2\\
A_\text{out} &= \sqrt 2 \cdot 10^{\frac{P_\text{out}}{20}}\\
&= 549.3701
\end{align}$$

Is this calculation correct to yield the amplitude of my output signal when the output power in dBm is given? Or do I have to calculate power in dBW first? I assume an average output power of $P_{out} = A_{out}^2/2$

Comment: your second line, $P_\text{out} = 10\log_{10}{\frac{A^2}2}$ makes a physical assumption that doesn't generally hold. Ask yourself: What is the power of a voltage signal without specifying the impedance it drives or the current?

Comment: In other words: No, you cannot derive the physical amplitude of a signal from it's physical power if you don't specify the physical system you're observing/that the power flows into. For example, to generate 1W of heat over a 1MΩ resistor, you'd need a lot more amplitude than to generate 1W of heat over a 1 Ω resistor.

Comment: you're right, of course. I edited my question.

Comment: So my problem with your edited question is still: if you use physical units (dBm), amplitude square is still not a power, as discussed in my other comment. You're missing the units of your power-to-amplitude-square relation, and since that defines the answer to the question "should I be using dBm or dBW" (you probably should not use either, judging by the struggle you're having with the physical aspect of this), your question remains impossible to answer!

Answer (score 5):

The Decibel Miliwatts Scale [$dBm$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm) is the power ratio in Decibels, considering a reference of $P_0=1mW$.

$$P[dB]=10\text{log}_{10}(P/P_0)=10\text{log}_{10}(P[W]/0.001)$$

The general context is considering the signal amplitude $V$ in $volts$ and the power as an *impedance load system* $R$ in $\Omega$:

$$P=\frac{1}{R}V^2$$

Moreover, *sinusoidal excitations* are considered (for a given frequency also!), so we also can have:
$$P=\frac{1}{R}V_{rms}^2=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{R}V_{pk}^2$$

Thus:

$$
P[dBm] = 10\text{log}_{10}\left(\frac{V[V]^2}{R[\Omega]}\frac{1}{P_0}\right) = 20\text{log}_{10}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{R[\Omega]}}\frac{V[V]}{\sqrt{P_0}}\right)
$$

So, [as reference](http://ifmaxp1.ifm.uni-hamburg.de/DBM.shtml):

- $1W$ equals $30dBm$,
- for a $50\Omega$ impedance system, this also equals $7.07V$, and
- under the sinusoidal case, this also equals $10V_{pk}$ and $7.07V_{rms}$.